# resize from lvm disk for use in docker container

Tags: partitioning, docker, lvm, oracle-linux

I have an EC2 on AWS, and one more attached disk.

[image: return command lsblk]

I increased the disk size, and did the resize. But inside that partition is Docker, and in it I have a container with Oracle Linux 7.8.

Even doing this rezise, the container doesn't understand this new value, and it still remains with the old value of 59GB.

In container:
[image]

[image]

I would like to know how I do the resize inside the container, or in this case, in oracle Linux maybe, I don't know. But I need this `dm` to have the total value of the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the issue is you've resized the LVM volume but not the sparse file backing the DM device.

That needs a little more work.

This article seems to cover it nicely, just note the comments towards the end.

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/

Comment: I did according to the principles of the tutorial, and it worked! Some points in my case didn't make sense, so I changed it. And all this without having to remove container, or image. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are most welcome!